# How do I fetch the keys from a service response, which is a key value kind of response, in KarateDSL?

Tags: karate, rest

The response of a service returns data in following form,

{
"data": {
"2020-01-01": 131.016,
"2020-01-02": 151.039,
"2020-01-03": 142.593,
"2020-01-04": 136.516,
"2020-01-05": 128.969,
"2020-01-06": 123.906,
"2020-01-07": 125.177,
"2020-01-08": 120.031,
"2020-01-09": 110.677,
"2020-01-10": 108.514
}
}

Now, I want to fetch all the dates here so that it can be used to perform specific actions for subsequent service calls. Can you please help?

Expected Result -
"2020-01-01"
"2020-01-02"
"2020-01-03"
"2020-01-04"
"2020-01-05"
"2020-01-06"
"2020-01-07"
"2020-01-08"
"2020-01-09"
"2020-01-10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object) API or [JsonPath](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-jsonpath) for any operations in your response JSON

you can use [karate.keysOf()](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-keysOf) try,

```
karate.keysOf(response.data)
```

this extracts all the keys of any given json.